# Change SegmentedControl index from another viewcontroller before collectionview reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segmentedcontrol

So the problem I'm having is that I have a `CollectionView` that loads different data depending on the `index`. If, for example, I'm at `index 0` and the first `cell` is "hat" and I switch to `index 1` and the first `cell` is "coat". The problem is if I click on the "coat" and then click the `Back button`... it shows the coat but we're really still on "hat". And if you click on the "coat" it will bring up the details for the "hat".

I solved a similar problem before by just reloading the `CollectionView` upon pressing the `back button`... but that doesn't seem to be working this time. So what I want to do is make sure the `segmented control index` is set to `0` before the reload.

Here's what I have so far from the Hat/Coat `detailview`:

```
UserViewController *userVC = [[UserViewController alloc] init];
[userVC.collectionView reloadData];
```

And here's the code for the `segmented control` in the `UserViewController`:

```
HMSegmentedControl * segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 600, 50)];
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
```

I can't quite figure out the code to change that index from the `detail view`. Or, if that wouldn't work, to just get it to reload the whole view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults.

In AppDelegate :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([userDefaults objectForKey:@"segmentedControlIndex"] == nil) {
    [userDefaults setInteger:0 forKey:@"segmentedControlIndex"];
}
```

In viewWillAppear function :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:[userDefaults integerForKey:@"segmentedControlIndex"]];
```

And on switch :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setInteger:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex forKey:@"segmentedControlIndex"];
```

Comment: Not working. First it won't let me do self.segmentedControl because it says that object is not found on type UserView. So if I load it as shown above in my question and then do segmentedControl instead of self.segmentedControl... then it doesn't show the error... but it also doesn't work.